# EF Core generate b-tree but not a btree in postgres

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

EF Core 8.0.1 generate b-tree SQL code for Postgres. When I'm trying to apply migration on a server, it produces a Postgres error

```
2024-02-12T23:41:35.418441849Z 12.02.2024 23:41:35.418+00:00 [ERR] (1) Failed executing DbCommand ("12"ms) [Parameters=[""], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"\n""CREATE INDEX ix_recipes_cooking_level ON foods.recipes USING b-tree (cooking_level);" (ActionId:,RequestId:)
2024-02-12T23:41:35.441575197Z Unhandled exception. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near "-"
2024-02-12T23:41:35.441631718Z 
2024-02-12T23:41:35.441653635Z POSITION: 63
```

How I should configure EF Core?

Comment: `.. USING b-tree ..` not `.. USING btree ..`? how did you create the index in ef? fyi, [postgres default to `btree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) and you don't have to specify it using `HasMethod("b-tree")` - which is a typo.

Comment: This is not created by me. This sql generated by EF when you write db.Database. Migrate()

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. There was an issue with creating indexing fields in builder model. For those how will participate in same issue - check your model builder first